# Does boto3 support VPC endpoint connection to S3

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

We have a Python client that connects to the Amazon S3 via a VPC endpoint.   Our code uses boto and we are able to connect and download from S3.

After migration from boto to boto3, we noticed that the VPC endpoint connection no longer works.  Below is a copy snippet that can reproduce the problem.

```sh
python -c "import boto3;
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
       aws_access_key_id='foo',
       aws_secret_access_key='bar');
s3.Bucket('some-bucket').download_file('hello-remote.txt', 
                                       'hello-local.txt')"
```

got the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3-1.4.0-py2.7.egg\boto3\s3\inject.py",
line 163, in bucket_download_file
    ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3-1.4.0-py2.7.egg\boto3\s3\inject.py",
line 125, in download_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto3-1.4.0-py2.7.egg\boto3\s3\transfer.py
", line 269, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\s3transfer\futures.py", line 73, in result
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\s3transfer\futures.py", line 233, in result
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', e
rror(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not pro
perly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because c
onnected host has failed to respond'))
```

Does anyone know if boto3 support connection to S3 via VPC endpoint and/or was able to get it to work?  We are using boto3-1.4.0.

Comment: Hi. We are seeing the same thing currently. Running a Lambda function using boto3 to download from S3 works from one VPC, but when moved to a VPC with an Endpoint, it times out. Good to know it's not just us!

Comment: I believe you need to setup the subnets, it is a common problem. Check if the VPC subnets are correctly configured and the lambda subnet are the same as configured to the VPC, also remember to check the security group (should be the same)

Comment: Is is still an issue? Because I just tested it and there are no problems connecting to s3 using lambda in a private subnet through VPC S3 endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a configuration error in your VPC endpoint policies. If your policies are correct, then Boto3 never knows exactly how it's able to reach the S3 location, it really is up to the policies to allow/forbid this type of traffic.

Here's a quick walkthrough of what you can do for troubleshooting: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint/

Other relevant docs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-access.html#vpc-endpoint-policies
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#vpc-endpoints-policies-s3

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your AWS policies and roles defined.
Shortest way to make your code run is to make the S3 bucket Public [ not recommended]
else add your IP in the security policies and then re-run the code.
Details of it can be found here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Use IP whitelisting to secure your AWS Transfer for SFTP servers
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/use-ip-whitelisting-to-secure-your-aws-transfer-for-sftp-servers/